# Unable to pass data to a POST request using Volley library - Android

Tags: php, android, http-post, android-volley

I am trying to send a firebase push notification from my server. I trigger the .php file by sending a POST request using Volley like this:

```
public static void dataPacket(Activity activity, Map<String, String> bundle)
    {
        new AsyncTask<String, Boolean, Boolean>()
        {
            protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params)
            {
                String url  = CloudData.TEST_DATA_PACKET;
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(activity);

                StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                        response -> {
                            // response
                            Log.d("Response", response);
                        },
                        error -> {
                            error.printStackTrace();
                            Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
                        }
                ) {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams()
                    {
                        return bundle;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders()
                    {
                        Map<String, String>  headerParams = new HashMap<>();
                        headerParams.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

                        return headerParams;
                    }//*/
                };

                postRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                        10000,
                        0,
                        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));//*/

                queue.add(postRequest);
                return true;
            }
        }.execute();
    }
```

This is my .php file in my server:

```
<?php
    require 'FCMPushNotification.php'; 

    $FCMPushNotification = new \BD\FCMPushNotification('MY_API_KEY');

    $sDeviceToken = $_POST['token'];

    $aPayload = array(
        'data' => array("test"=>123),
        'notification' => array(
            'title' => 'Example app',
            'body'=> 'This is an example message',
            'sound'=> 'default'
        )
    );

    $aOptions = array(
        'time_to_live' => 0 //means messages that can't be delivered immediately are discarded. 
    );

    $aResult = $FCMPushNotification->sendToDevice(
        $sDeviceToken,      
        $aPayload,
        $aOptions // optional
    );

    var_dump($aResult);  

 ?>
```

When I change this line

```
$sDeviceToken = $_POST['token'];
```

to this

```
$sDeviceToken = 'my_firebase_token_for_a_device';
```

everything works fine. But when I try to get the variable 'token' from POST request android gives me this error:

> BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for
>   https://mywebsite.com/sendnotification.php   W/System.err:
>   com.android.volley.ServerError  W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:179)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:114) 
>   D/Error.Response: com.android.volley.ServerError

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

This is how I call dataPacket:

```
PostTaskListener<String> postTaskListener = result ->
        {
            bundle.put("token",result); 
            SendNotification.dataPacket(activity,bundle);
        };
        FirebaseCloud.getFirebaseToken(db.getActiveProfile().cID,postTaskListener,activity);
```

Comment: And where is the body of the POST request with aforementioned array that contains 'token' value?

Comment: I tried passing another POST variable and putting this variable as the title of the push notification. The notification came with empty title.

Comment: You specify body format as application/json, and put through as an array(form-data), that may be affecting the result.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov you are correct, that was the problem. If you want answer the question properly so I can accept the answer.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov btw what should I put as Content-type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specified body format as application/json, and put through as an array(form-data), that may be affecting the result. The format should be [multipart/form-data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Form-Data) (or application/x-www-form-urlencoded, as per wiki).

Comment: what should I put as Content-type?